# Вопрос про монетки

Tags: теория-вероятностей

Есть 3 монетки, на одной из них с обеих сторон орел.
Случайно берут одну монету и бросают. Какова вероятность что выпадет орел?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всего имеется шесть граней - четыре орла и две решки. Соответственно, шанс выпадения орла составляет 2/3.

Comment: Это Вы хорошо скрылись за «Community wiki». Вас какая, простите, сволочь научила вероятность в проценты переводить? Вероятность **никогда** не измеряется в процентах, не смейте идти на поводу у массового заблуждения!

Comment: 0.67, если Вам угодно

Comment: это не мне угодно, так положено. И зачем эти округления, когда Вы уже дали более точный ответ: 2/3?) Задачи «округлите ответ до сотых» не стояло) И не поймите, пожалуйста, мое негодование превратно: я ни в коем случае не хотел Вас оскорбить или обидеть, я просто пытаюсь бороться с общепринятым заблуждением

Comment: Одного заблуждающегося гуманитария Вы точно побороли )

Comment: Че за бред, при чем здесь грани? Случайно берут 1 из трёх монет. В одном из трёх случаев орёл выпадет при любом исходе броска.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk: у Вас, смотрю, с математикой совсем все плохо

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, да, вообще плохо. (

Comment: Никакого "заблуждения" тут нет. Вероятность, несомненно, можно и нужно выражать в процентах. Другое дело, что для представления 2/3 в процентах понадобится периодическая дробь, поэтому в данном случае действительно лучше использовать обыкновенную дробь.